# Nice Formula for a Function from $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$

Tags: functions

I am trying to get a nice formula for the following function
$$f:\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\rightarrow \{1,1,-1,3,-3,5,-5,7,-7,9,-9,...\}$$
thus
It seems like it would be closely related to somthing like $f(n)=(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)$?  It looks like for even numbers,
$$f(2k)=(1-2k)(-1)^{2k-1}$$
and for odd numbers
$$f(2k-1)=(2k-1)$$
These are related but are not the same function.  How can i make this work?

Comment: You have 1 twice in your set on the left hand set. I guess the first should be zero?

Comment: You already GAVE the explicit bijection, what you're looking for is a "nice formula".

Comment: @avid19, yes you are right.  Calle, it should be as it is: so you could say $a_0=1. a_1=1, a_2=-1, a_3=3,...$.

Comment: So $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 1$? Then it is not a bijection.

Comment: You are right.  I changed it to a function.  It was a bijection when I disregarded $a_0$, but I actually need it.

Comment: Did i get downvoted because of my wording?  I think I fixed it to more accurately reflect what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use $ \displaystyle f(n)=(-1)^{n+1}\left(2\big
\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\big\rfloor-1\right)$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor of $x$.